# Set a block region from the block edit page

Tags: 7, theming

I used Drupal since 4, and it always bothered me that the the block edit page doesn't include block region settings. One must return to the Blocks list to change that. It would be so much nicer if the block edit page included the region options, when using the contextual Configure links on the page.

There is no module dedicated to this on Drupal.org, so maybe there is a good reason for not doing this, like a technical limitation. Or maybe this is not useful to anyone else but me.

Is there a module for setting the block region from the block edit page? I'll create one if there isn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 you have the option to set the region of the block within the block's edit page.

I haven't seen a module for this for Drupal 6 let alone earlier versions. I would strongly recommend upgrading to Drupal 7 for this feature and the plethora of other desirable features of Drupal 7 compared to it's predecessors.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to know it's in D7. However, upgrading is not an option.